# Hourly sum of values

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table with the following structure and sample data:

```
STORE_ID |  INS_TIME  | TOTAL_AMOUNT
  2         07:46:01    20
  3         19:20:05    100
  4         12:40:21    87
  5         09:05:08    5
  6         11:30:00    12
  6         14:22:07    100
```

I need to get the hourly sum of TOTAL_AMOUNT for each STORE_ID.
I tried the following query but i don't know if it's correct.

```
SELECT STORE_ID, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) , HOUR(INS_TIME) as HOUR FROM VENDAS201302 
WHERE MINUTE(INS_TIME) <=59
GROUP BY HOUR,STORE_ID
ORDER BY INS_TIME;
```

Comment: show Result Data what you need, would be easier.

Comment: How do you define "hourly"?  What is your **RDBMS** (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle, etc.)?  What is the data type of INS_TIME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT STORE_ID,  
       HOUR(INS_TIME) as HOUR_OF_TIME,
       SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) as AMOUNT_SUM
FROM VENDAS201302 
GROUP BY STORE_ID, HOUR_OF_TIME
ORDER BY INS_TIME;
```

Comment: Erroneous comma after `AMOUNT_SUM`. [Here's a fiddle for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed97d/1)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are not considering different days here. You could get the hourly sum using `Datepart()` function as below in Sql-Server:

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41dd1/3)

```
SELECT STORE_ID, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) HOURLY_SUM
FROM t1
GROUP BY STORE_ID, datepart(hour,convert(datetime,INS_TIME))
ORDER BY STORE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kaf, in fact there is a "Day" column but I suppressed it from the question. I'm using SQL in SAS and I'm not sure if there is the datepart function available.

Comment: No problem, I wasn't sure about the database server at the time.